# NodeJS only listens on localhost

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I have developed a [NestJS Server](https://nestjs.com/) application. NestJs is a node server running with express written in TypeScript.

Now I want to deploy the application on my rapsberry pi. However, I'm only able to access the server from localhost. If I try to access from a different client no content is returned. (The "^C" in the picture is only the cancel sign ;D)

I already set the hostname to `0.0.0.0`. What else can I do?

```
# /src/main.ts 
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3001, '0.0.0.0');
}
```

[image: See picture]

Comment: Can you see if the request is leaving your local machine and coming back in through the firewall?  You may need to open firewall ports.

Comment: I already deleted all my iptable rules and set the default policy to ACCEPT.

Comment: can you try listenAsync instead of listen? https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/interfaces/nest-application.interface.ts#L55

Comment: I tried it. But the problem stays the same :(

Comment: @RoseNettoyeur Have you opend the ports in your router firewall? From your screenshot it seems you try to access your "public" / WAN IP of your router. To get this working (when it works from LAN) you need to open port 3001 in your rooter too. Side note: Its possible that this still not works because your router cant working with hairpin nat. Try this with your smartphone connected to LTE and no WiFi.

Comment: That IP address is not the IP address of your pi. Try browsing that ipinfo page from your PC/laptop and you will see that it returns the same IP address. That IP address is the address of your router. You need to configure your router to forward all requests to port 3001 to your raspberry pi's ip address port 3001 (eg. forward port 3001 to 192.168.0.10 port 3001 - assuming your pi is at 192.168.0.10). How to do this is different from one router manufacturer to another and even one model to another (eg. how to do port forwarding for Linksys WRT54G vs Linksys MR7500)

Comment: Note that with port forwarding it is possible to forward "normal" ports to special ports. For example forward requests to port 80 and port 443 to your raspberry pi port 3001

Answer (score 0):

You must open firewall port and service, see below (this works for CentOS box):

```sh
#add port
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=3001/tcp  --permanent

# add service
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http

# reload !!! IMPORTANT !!!
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The OS is a fresh raspbian. There is no firewall by default and I didn't have installed one. I also deleted all IP-Table rules and set the default policy to ACCEPT. Didn't help. Same problem :(

Comment: I've run simple node app on my RasberryPi box and it looks like it's accessible in LAN via server IP out of the box - perhaps because I have LAMP server configured and working ?

Comment: No! No do that. Please. Configure your application with your programming frameworks, as secure your local environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000; // Choose your desired port

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World!');
});

// Change from 'localhost' to '0.0.0.0'
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain how this can solve the problem? Thank you